# R: Plotting one ECDF on top of another in different colors

Tags: r, plot, ecdf

I have a couple of cumulative empirical density functions which I would like to plot on top of each other in order to illustrate differences in the two curves. As was pointed out [in a previous question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7fIq.png), the function to draw the ECDF is simply `plot(Ecdf())` And as I read the fine manual page, I determined that I can plot multiple ECDFs on top of each other using something like the following:

```
require( Hmisc )
set.seed(3)
g <- c(rep(1, 20), rep(2, 20))  
Ecdf(c( rnorm(20), rnorm(20)), group=g)
```

However my curves sometimes overlap a bit and can be hard to tell which is which, just like the example above which produces this graph:

[image]

I would really like to make the color of these two CDFs different. I can't figure out how to do that, however. Any tips?

Comment: Time to switch from Guiness back to coffee, JD. There is a `col=` argument, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If memory serves, I have done this in the past.  As I recall, you needed to trick it as `Ecdf()` is so darn paramterised.  I think in `help(ecdf)` it hints that it is just a plot of stepfunctions, so you could estimate two or more ecdfs, plot one and then annotate via `lines()`.

***Edit***  Turns out it is as easy as

```
  R> Ecdf(c(rnorm(20), rnorm(20)), group=g, col=c('blue', 'orange'))
```

as the help page clearly states the `col=` argument.  But I have also found some scriptlets where I used `plot.stepfun()` explicitly.

Comment: It is CLEARLY stated in the manuals, which I thought I read. Obviously my glass of Guinness was blocking that part of the screen.

Comment: Wow, they do 64oz 'gulp' glasses now?

Comment: When I landed in DUB they hooked me to an IV bag of Guinness. It was the IV bag blocking my screen.

Answer (score 7):

You can add each curve one at a time (each with its own style), e.g.

```
Ecdf(rnorm(20), lwd = 2)
Ecdf(rnorm(20),add = TRUE, col = 'red', lty = 1)
```

Comment: You can do it one operation too as `col`, `lty`, ... are all vectorised.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `Ecdf` (doesn't look like `Hmisc` is available):

```
set.seed(3)
mat <- cbind(rnorm(20), rnorm(20))
matplot(apply(mat, 2, sort), seq(20)/20, type='s')
```