# How to plot multiple ECDF's on one plot in different colors in R

Tags: r, plot, ecdf

I am trying to plot 4 ecdf functions on one plot but can't seem to figure out the proper syntax.

If I have 4 functions "A, B, C, D" what would be the proper syntax in R to get them to be plotted on the same chart with different colors.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package `latticeExtra` provides the function [`ecdfplot`](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#ecdfplot).

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

set.seed(42)
vals <- data.frame(r1=rnorm(100)*0.5,
                   r2=rnorm(100),
                   r3=rnorm(100)*2)

ecdfplot(~ r1 + r2 + r3, data=vals, auto.key=list(space='right')
```

[image: ecdfplot with legend]

Comment: Is it possible to get ECDF of all columns of the dataframe and avoid the "+" sign in the code.

Answer (score 15):

Here is one way (for three of them, works for four the same way):

```
set.seed(42)
ecdf1 <- ecdf(rnorm(100)*0.5)
ecdf2 <- ecdf(rnorm(100)*1.0)
ecdf3 <- ecdf(rnorm(100)*2.0)
plot(ecdf3, verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE)
plot(ecdf2, verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE, add=TRUE, col='brown')
plot(ecdf1, verticals=TRUE, do.points=FALSE, add=TRUE, col='orange')
```

Note that I am using the fact that the third has the widest range, and use that to initialize the canvas. Else you need `ylim=c(...)`.

[image]

Comment: So if your memory was correct 2.5 years ago, then this is the third time you answered the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344081/r-plotting-one-ecdf-on-top-of-another-in-different-colors?rq=1

Comment: ==:-)  You just made my day. I may need a tutorial about searching here because I looked for an old answer but didn't find it rightaway.  Mind you, 2 1/2 years ago I only said I knew I had _done_ it before, not answered.  And today's answer is all base R, no Hmisc, so there. ;-)

Comment: Search on: user:143305 ecdf .... and you will find others from earlier as well although the one I'm thinking of was with `Hmisc::Ecdf`. (Sometimes it's just easier doing it again.)

Comment: Something odd there Dirk, looks like clipping got turned off somewhere as you produced that figure.

Comment: That is AFAIK a rather old bug in R.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an approach using `ggplot2` (using the ecdf objects from [Dirk's answer])(https://stackoverflow.com/a/20601807/1385941)

```
library(ggplot2)
# create a data set containing the range you wish to use
d <- data.frame(x = c(-6,6))
# create a list of calls to `stat_function` with the colours you wish to use

ll <- Map(f  = stat_function, colour = c('red', 'green', 'blue'),
          fun = list(ecdf1, ecdf2, ecdf3), geom = 'step')


ggplot(data = d, aes(x = x)) + ll
```

[image]

Comment: do you know how to add legend?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use ggplot and have the variable that you want to plot as a factor.  In the example below, I have Portfolio as a factor and plotting the distribution of Interest Rates by Portfolio.

```
# select a palette
myPal <- c( 'royalblue4', 'lightsteelblue1', 'sienna1')

# plot the Interest Rate distribution of each portfolio
# make an ecdf of each category in Portfolio which is a factor
g2 <- ggplot(mortgage, aes(x = Interest_Rate, color = Portfolio)) + 
      scale_color_manual(values = myPal) +
      stat_ecdf(lwd = 1.25, geom = "line")
      
g2
```

You can also set `geom = "step", geom = "point"` and adjust the line width `lwd` in the `stat_ecdf()` function.  This gives you a nice plot with the legend.

[image]